# Clean a list of lists from GoogleSheets in R

Tags: r

I have retrieved a sheet from google sheets and returned me a list of lists:

```
sheet <- list(var1 = list(Sys.time(), Sys.time(),NULL),
             var2 = list(NULL,1,2),
             var3 = list("a",NULL,"b"))
```

I have to convert all members of the list that are `NULL` into `NAs`. I was kindly explained how to do it list by list using for example `sheet$var1[sapply(sheet$var1,is.null)] <- NA`, but since I have many variables, is it possible to code it in just one line? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a nested list.  So we can do

```
library(purrr)
map(sheet, ~ map(.x, ~ replace(.x, is.null(.x), NA)))
```

Or with `base R`

```
lapply(sheet, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) replace(y, is.null(y), NA)))
#$var1
#$var1[[1]]
#[1] "2020-09-13 16:44:56 CDT"

#$var1[[2]]
#[1] "2020-09-13 16:44:56 CDT"

#$var1[[3]]
#[1] NA


#$var2
#$var2[[1]]
#[1] NA

#$var2[[2]]
#[1] 1

#$var2[[3]]
#[1] 2


#$var3
#$var3[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#$var3[[2]]
#[1] NA

#$var3[[3]]
#[1] "b"
```

---

Or do this recursively with `rrapply`

```
library(rrapply)
rrapply(sheet, f = function(x) replace(x, is.null(x), NA), how = "list")
```

Comment: How great is to read an answer that makes me investigate more, now this function `rapply` and `rrapply` (a recursive apply) are in my to-study list. Thank you for you time @akrun.